# Postfix auth problem

Tags: postfix, sasl

```
Apr  1 21:05:05 Lucid postfix/smtpd[6230]: warning: xxx: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: no mechanism available
Apr  1 21:05:05 Lucid postfix/smtpd[6230]: warning: SASL authentication problem: unknown password verifier
```

I can't figure this out, I've been searching for hours, any help? What can I provide to solve this?

main.cf

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
myhostname = Lucid
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-destinations.cf
relayhost = 
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-forwards.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-e2e.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-boxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
disable_vrfy_command = yes
transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-transports.cf
virtual_create_maildirsize = yes
virtual_mailbox_extended = yes
virtual_mailbox_limit_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-limits.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit_override = yes
virtual_maildir_limit_message = "Account is over quota"
virtual_overquota_bounce = yes
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
```

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways to do SASL authentication in postfix dovecot and cyrus. You need to set the smtpd_sasl_type option in main.cf and configure the other options depending on your choice of authentication type.

The various options are documented here http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html